# Identificar duas teclas modificadoras pressionadas

Tags: c#, winforms

Como identificar que duas teclas estão pressionadas dentro de um evento click de um button?
Exemplo:

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Click += Btn_Click;

private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Assim consigo identificar que uma tecla está pressionada.
    // Gostaria de identificar o Control e Shift
    if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
    {
         MessageBox("Control pressionado");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O tipo [`Keys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx) é uma máscara de *bits* (uma combinação de *bits*)

Desta forma, você pode usar operações binárias para checar se mais de um modificador está pressionado

```
if (Control.ModifierKeys == (Keys.Control | Keys.Shift))
{
     MessageBox("Control e Shift pressionados");
}
```

Note que você pode usar a propriedade [**`Modifiers`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.modifiers(v=vs.110).aspx) em [`KeyEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
if (e.Modifiers == (Keys.Control | Keys.Shift))
{
    //Control e Shift pressionados
}
```